# How to add a textbreak in phpword?

Tags: php, phpword

I use the "phpword" class to generate a .doc file, but i have the problem:

how to add a line break for this problem?, so for example I have the following text:

Code (in a variable):

**"This is

a text

With line break"**

Now if we enter that into the word document...will display this:

**"This is a text With line break."**

how can i do this? i want the text in the word document with this style:

**This is

a text

With line break**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with phpword. You have to split the string in lines and use `addTextBreak`.

```
<?php
$text = "This is
a text
With line break";

$lines = explode("\n", $text);

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $doc->addText($line);
    $doc->addTextBreak();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but then with altering a template file. It is really not possible to add linebreaks, the `setValue` function only works with normal strings.

But if you like to try a dirty fix, you could add the following line to `Template.php` @line 91:

```
$replace = preg_replace('~\R~u', '</w:t><w:br/><w:t>', $replace);
```

It's dirty because you're not sure the last tag is a `<w:t>` tag; it could be something else. But this will do the trick most times: it replaces a newline `\n` to the `<w:br>` tag Word uses for a line break.

Answer (score 0):

```
function add_entered_text( $textrun, $text, $par1, $par2  ){

  $textlines = explode("\n", $text);
  $textrun->addText(array_shift($textlines), $par1, $par2);
  foreach($textlines as $line) { 
      $textrun->addText($line, $par1, $par2);
  }

}
```

Example:

```
add_entered_text( $section, $text1, $header, $style );

add_entered_text( $section, $text2, null, $style );

add_entered_text( $table->addCell(4000, $cellRowSpan), $text3, null, $style );
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is replacing '/n' with '<w:br/>' in string

```
str_replace("\n", '<w:br/>', $text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered a much better solution. This can search for a particular character or string inside the INPUT string and replace it with a linebreak:

```
$str = preg_replace('<br />', '/w:t><w:rPr><w:lang w:val="en-IN"/></w:rPr><w:br/><w:t',  $str );
```

Let me know if it help.